# Finding time to target with variable velocity

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

so i have torpedos in my game and they start out at 0 meters per second and accelerate realistically. after so many seconds they stop accelerating and travel at a constant rate forward.

I have a distance to the target and I basically am trying to calculate lead time for autoaiming.

So given

Distance to target;

Acceleration (per second);

burn time (number of seconds before acceleration stops);

I need to basically determine I believe the average meters per second the projectile is travelling.

The only way I can see to do it is something like this.

```
        curdistance; //stores distance traveled per second
        currentspeed; //stores speed at a given second
        acceleration;

        for(int timer = 1; curdistance < distanceToTarget;timer++)
{
        currentspeed = currentspeed + acceleration; 
        curdistance = curdistance + ( currentspeed);

    if(timer >= burnTime)
    {
    acceleration = 0;
    }

}
```

Now this works but it has 2 problems.

The burn time has to be an int or else the smaller the fraction the greater the number of runs to keep accuracy.

If i want a 4.2 burn time for example in order to keep the accuracy i have to run it 42 times and calculate for every 10th of a second.

Also the average could be off by quite a bit depending on how much it overshoots a target depending again on how precise the timer is.

if my projectile is going at 30 meters per second and it needs to go 121 meters it'll add another full second of travel before it goes ok you've gone to/past the target which will mean it will actualy be aiming as it were at a point 29 meters further than it really should.

The only way to combat this with this algorithm is to check more often every 10th or 100th of a second.

I feel like though there might be a math equation I don't know that lets me solve this precisely.

Any Help?

Comment: It's not clear to me what do you want to ultimate calculate (the sentence "I need to basically determine I believe the average meters per second the projectile is travelling" hints that you need to calculate speed instead of time). Do you want the time taken for the projectile to hit its target?

Comment: As you describe it your movement happens in 2 parts. The first part is accelerated movement (with constant acceleration) and the second part is movement under constant velocity. All you need to do is calculate the travelling time for each of those separately and then sum it together.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you want to solve for here.  Do you need to know distance and velocity as a function of time?  I am sure that it can be done/solved, but it just isn't clear exactly what you want solved.  Try to define it as a Function declaration that you need implemented.

Comment: So this is not about programming, as if you knew the magic equation, you would be happy. Therefore, it is about physics, or at least mathematics, as if you understood numerical integration or even interpolation, again, you would be done.

Comment: @woodchips No, algorithms are a part of programming.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - but this is basic physics.

Comment: @woodschips: It's also basic math.  It's also mid-level programming and basic games programming.  It can be more than one thing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - if you understand the freshman physics needed to write down the equation, the solution is trivial. This is my point. IF you don't understand that, then it looks complex, which it is truly not. This makes the problem a physics one, not programming. Otherwise by your definition, EVERYTHING is just programming.

Comment: @woodchips Not in the least bit true.  Saying that something is "*basic*" anything does not make it off-topic, quite the opposite in fact.  The basics of any discipline are readily subsumed by aligned disciplines, so saying that something is basic physics (like the high-school acceleration formula), or basic math (like quadratic equations) does ***not*** mean that it is not also a valid basic programming question.  If it was a more *advanced* physics problem (like say calculating the Coriolis force for a moving mass a a point on the earth's surface), *then* you'd have a point.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm inclined to agree with woodchips here. While the question, as it stands, is not appropriate for either [math.se] or [physics.se], I believe that the essence of what OP wants belongs on one of those two. Or maybe just [gamedev.se] then.

Comment: just to emphasize what I want.  I want to auto aim so what i'm trying to do is calculate how far along in front of the "target" i need to be to aiming to hit it. leading the target. The way i determine lead is for a bullet (simple case) meters per second / distance to target gives me how many seconds it is to target. Then I take the target and use its meters per second and current position to find the position X number of seconds from now. So if the target stays on its heading i'll hit it square. (minus whatever small discrepency there is in the distance to target now and distance later.)

Comment: The issue is right now I can't use the torpedos max speed because due to it taking several seconds to reach its speed it takes 1 to 2 more seconds for example than max speed would suggest to get to the target so i'm too slow and shoot behind the target because of acceleration. I want to remove that by calculating average speed to target so it arrives when it thinks it will.

Comment: Also I did consider posting this question on a physics forum but I want code. Most places (this included often) aren't going to help you out if you dont show a good faith effort to solve the problem yourself and contribute something. However my attempt was using a for loop. If you don't understand for loops you don't understand my attempt to solve using brute force. If i just go and post hey tell me how I won't get help (and perhaps rightfully so) on a phsyics forum. People who program however tend to have strong math skills so you can help and since i did try to you are more likely to.

Comment: @sparkzbarca: Your approach (the way you describe for the bullet) will still miss if the target is moving sideways and the bullet is too slow. If you want to hit moving targets accurately then you will need to use vector arithmetic. Are the targets moving in 2D/3D?

Comment: @sparkzbarca: Also check my answer below, it does exactly what you asked in your (original) question. Given distance to target, acceleration and burn time it calculates the average speed (and also time to target). However if the target is moving it won't always work in this way. You will have to represent both target and projectile movement as vectors (in 2D or 3D) and calculate the right projectile vector (the angle) so that it will hit the moving target, which is a bit more complicated than just calculating linear movement.

Comment: if you mean like for calculating the point to aim at. I mean to get the point to aim at I am going to use the average speed to the target distance then the point I aim at will be the current target position plus the target velocity (as a vector, so its movement in all 3 directions with all 3 individual meters per second in each direction accounted for) * number of seconds to target. So if the target is going 10,0,0  it will aim at target position + 30,0,0 if its 3 seconds away. The aiming itself i've already programmed as far as given a vector aim at it. THANKS FOR HELP! :)

Comment: the targets are moving in 3d by the way. (i'm using unity game engine if you know what that is) So it has lots of built in vector/quanternion algorithms but i'm not sure why the target going sideways would matter as long as i'm aiming 3 seconds in front of the target and it is 3 seconds from the launcher to the target.

Answer (score 2):

During accelerated motion you can use `d = a*t^2/2`, or equivalently `t = sqrt(2*d/a)`, at which time velocity `v = a*t`.
Then you can extrapolate to the target using that `v`.

Comment: so time in seconds is square root of ((2distance) / acceleration))? Is there a common math name for that function? Just for more info. So basically I use the T function to solve for T. Modify it to solve for A and then the average velocity to from the torpedo launcher to the target is basically A * T?

Comment: @sparkzbarca: [*Look here*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration), and plug in zero for initial velocity *u*. A*T is the velocity at time T when under acceleration A, not the average velocity. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

As you describe it your movement happens in 2 parts. The first part is accelerated movement (with constant acceleration) and the second part is movement under constant velocity.

You can calculate the traveling distance (or time) for each one individually and then combine them for the desired result.

Keep in mind that you need to check for special cases where the target is closer than the burn distance. The code below does that with the check `if (distanceToTarget < burnDistance)`

```
// these will be the results
float timeToTarget; 
float averageSpeed;

// assign values to these
float distanceToTarget;    
float acceleration;     
float burnTime;

float burnDistance = acceleration * burnTime * burnTime * 0.5;

if (distanceToTarget < burnDistance)
{
    timeToTarget = Math.Sqrt(2 * distanceToTarget / acceleration);
}
else
{
    float velocity = acceleration * burnTime;
    timeToTarget = burnTime + (distanceToTarget - burnDistance) / velocity;
}

averageSpeed = distanceToTarget / timeToTarget;
```

Answer (score 1):

If

```
d = initial distance to the target
b = burn time
a = acceleration
```

When the projectile stops accelerating, it will have

```
speed = a*b
distance (traveled) = dt = a*b^2/2
```

From that moment, it will need

```
time for impact = ti = (d-dt)/(a*b)
```

The total time will be

```
total time for impact = ti + b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
Function VelocityGivenTime(burnTime, givenTime)
(
    T = givenTime
    If T > burnTime Then T = burnTime

    return acceleration * T
)

Function DistanceGivenTime(burnTime, givenTime)
(
    If burntime >= givenTime Then
        T = givenTime
        return 0.5 * acceleration * T^2
    Else
        T = burnTime
        D = 0.5 * acceleration * T^2
        D = D + VelocityGivenTime(T) * (givenTime - burnTime)
        return D
    End IF
)
```

However, if what you really wanted was the time to a target give its distance, you could do it like this:

```
Function TimeGivenDistance(burnTime, distance)
(
    burnDistance = DistanceGivenTime(burnTime)

    If distance > burnDistance Then
        return burnTime + (distance - burnDistance) / VelocityGivenTime(burnTime)

    Else
        return SQRT(2 * distance / acceleration)
    End If
)
```